# jquery datatable apresentar detalhes

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable

Tenho um jQuery DataTable que possui detalhe, onde clica na linha a expande o tamplate de detalhe que faz uma requisição ao servidor e trás dados distintos da tabela principal, segui esse [Exemplo](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html)

Porém meu prolema agora é o seguinte, preciso que ao invés do tamplate ser um detalhe que expanda conforme o clique da linha, preciso que ele sempre fique visivel, um detalhe que não seja oculto. Minha dúvida está como fazer com que o datatable principal carregue automaticamente o detalhe já que ele faz uma requisição a parte.

No fim vou precisar dar um print no meu datatable principal, imprimindo ele e o detalhe.

Exemplo:

```
Coluna1| Coluna2| Coluna3|
Valor1   Valor2   Valor3
  Detalhe1| Detalhe2| Detalhe3|
  ValorD1   ValorD2   ValorD3
```

Comment: você quer que ele carregue e já permaneça aberto, mas não quer perder essa funcionalidade, ou seja, o botão de expandir/esconde deve continuar funcionando? Ou quer que apenas apareça os detalhes e elimine o botão de expandir/esconder?

Comment: Eu quero que apenas apareça os detalhes, eliminando o botão expandir/esconder, pois preciso fazer um print desse datatable depois.

Answer (score -2):

Comente tudo que estiver dentro de:

```
$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control', function () {
//comentar
});
```

E acrescente o código:

```
var trs = $('#example tbody tr');

for(var i = 0, len = trs.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var tr = trs[i];
    var row = dt.row( tr );
    row.child( format( row.data() ) ).show();
}
```

Para esconder os botões comente o css:

```
td.details-control {
    background: url('../resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.details td.details-control {
    background: url('../resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: Djalma, fiz conforme me falou, mas pelo que entendi, o exemplo ainda está sobre o click da coluna, o que eu preciso é que isso não ocorresse sobre nenhum clique, que fosse automático, sabe me dizer como faço para que isso aconteça?